# donot understand class not found exception

Tags: java

I am creating a login page for a Library Management System.In the below piece of code i am getting a class not found exception.But i donot understand which class is it talking about and why is this exception taking place.Moreover the HomeStudent class is already defined and all the classes in the same folder in the workspace.

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class MainClass extends Frame implements ActionListener {
    static MainClass instance ;
    Panel p = new Panel(new FlowLayout());
    Label uname = new Label("UserName");
    Label pass = new Label("Password");
    TextField tuname = new TextField(10);
    TextField tpass = new TextField(10);
    Button login = new Button("GO");
    public MainClass()
    {
        p.add(uname);
        p.add(tuname);
        p.add(pass);
        p.add(tpass);
        p.add(login);
        login.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         instance = new MainClass();
         instance.setVisible(true);
         instance.setSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //DataBase Part
        //Presently Done Simply
        //Simple If Else
        //Onlu Used for Prototyping
        if(tuname.getText().equals("user")&&(tpass.getText().equals("user")))
        {
            HomeStudent home = new HomeStudent();
            instance.setVisible(false);
            home.setVisible(true);
            home.setSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the stack trace.

```
load: class .class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .class
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace, please.

Comment: Please add entire error message.

Comment: Where is your class `HomeStudent` specified? I hope you are not getting `ClassNotFoundException` for that one.

Comment: How are you running the applet ?

Comment: What do you try to accomplish? The problem is that your class looks like a main class which has to be started by `java MainClass` but your stack trace shows that you try to run it as `Applet`. So what do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's talking about your main method.

```
public static void main(String args)
```

the String parameter MUST be a String array of args. It is what the main must take, and it is not, so that is where your error is. Just change to

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

and you should be all set.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think main method mentioned in Question has correct signature

Comment: @Jayesh That's because the OP edited it and corrected it after he saw this answer.

Comment: @RaduMurzea: My mistake..apologize.

Comment: that's alright :) we all make mistakes